# Drawing path stroke and shadow (iOS)

Tags: ios, drawing, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I'm using this code to create a rounded cornered image:

```
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageObj.size.width, imageObj.size.height);

    CGContextAddRect(context, rect);


CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextTranslateCTM (context, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
CGContextScaleCTM (context, ovalWidth, ovalHeight);
fw = CGRectGetWidth (rect) / ovalWidth;
fh = CGRectGetHeight (rect) / ovalHeight;
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, fw, fh/2);
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, fw, fh, fw/2, fh, 1);
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 0, fh, 0, fh/2, 1);
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 0, 0, fw/2, 0, 1);
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, fw, 0, fw, fh/2, 1);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);

CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextClip(context);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h), imageObj.CGImage);
```

How can I add a stroke and shadow?

Didn't work for me so far...

Thank you!

Comment: That path-drawing code draws an oval, not a rounded-cornered rectangle. For a rounded rectangle, you need to choose a corner radius, and then use that radius as the radius of each arc. The straight lines from one corner to the next will be included for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do either a  CGContextStrokePath or CGContextFillPath to draw the path you made. (make sure you set the stroke color first with CGContextSetStrokeColor) and then you can use CGContextSetShadow to make a shadow, here is an apple developer page describing CoreGraphics Shadows:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_shadows/dq_shadows.html

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that unsuccessfully, it didn't draw the line... more details on how to do that please?

Comment: @Asaaf b Is it possible your path is getting clipped that your trying to draw from CGContextClip

Comment: @Assaf b: I notice that you do a translate and scale, but then you grestore without doing anything. The translate and scale steps are unnecessary and wrong given that you then compute the transformed co-ordinates yourself, so they are doubly-transformed: Your drawing, if you were to actually draw, would be in the wrong place and too big. Also, `CGContextAddRect` will not give you rounded-corner anything. Throw out `AddRect`, translate, and scale; draw the path in a CGPath object, *then* gsave, add the path, set the shadow, and stroke, then grestore, re-add the path, clip, and draw the image.